# why does html img not get displayed in large screen devices of android webview?

Tags: android, html, css, image, webview

On my android, I have a webview that renders the image source. It works on small devices, but things like galaxy s4 does not work. The change I've made was the CSS, in which I updated in order for the image source to fit perfectly to the dimension of the webview.

HTML:

```
<body>

    <div class="radio_banners_app" style="overflow:hidden;">
       <img src="@Url.Content("~" + GraphicImagePath + item.Profile)" class="radio_app_img_src"/><br />    
     </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body > div.radio_banners_app {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

div.radio_banners_app > img.radio_app_img_src {
  margin:0 auto;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  position:absolute;
  min-width:100%;
  min-height:100%;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;

}
```

activity.java

```
URL = "~~~~"
    RadioBannerWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.RadioBannerWebview);
    RadioBannerWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    // javascript listener
    //MainWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
    //MainWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    RadioBannerWebView.loadUrl(URL);
```

After hours of search, I coulnd't seem to figure it out. please help!!

Comment: Maybe the problem is with the layout that contains the webview...

Comment: the img is of course smaller than the screen. As for Danyel, I'm using Linear Layout as the parent layout, and put WebView inside it